# How to secure a web service with ssl

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, ssl

I an building a Java EE application with Netbeans 7.3.2 using Javafx as a client to be served by web services from the EJB. I want to add SSL to secure the web services communication with the client over the network. I tried to add security to the web services but getting the following errors

```
SEVERE: WSS1601: Security Requirements not met - Transport binding configured in policy but incoming message was not SSL enabled
```

SEVERE: WSITPVD0035: Error in Verifying Security in Inbound Message.
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: WSS1601: Security Requirements not met - Transport binding configured in policy but incoming message was not SSL enabled

I have tried all means to get a tutorials online to help me do this since I am new to web services security and more so to configuring SSL for this.

Please can someone please help me with some tutorials or solution to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Web services are usually normal web applications in the background. So usually it is enough enabling SSL and assigning an SSL port at server side. For example in WebLogic open WebLogic admin console and set the followings:

- Environment/Servers/AdminServer/Configuration/SSL Listen Port Enabled
- Environment/Servers/AdminServer/Configuration/SSL Listen Port: 7004

Then at client side just change http to https and the non-SSL port to the SSL port in the URL of the web service.